# How do you insert into a table using a string containing the table's name?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

So I am using reflection and don't want to reference the table directly like this:

```
dbContext.Table1.Add(ob1);
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

I would rather do something like this:

```
dbContext.Find("Table1").Add(ob1);
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

Any ideas how to this using Entity Framework Core? (or other)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by using the code below.  dssObj can be a dbcontext of any time, so this works.

```
db.Entry(dssObj).State = EntityState.Added;
db.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
private string GetTableName()
        {
            var entityType = typeof(T);
            var modelEntityType = _db.Model.FindEntityType(entityType);

            string tableName = modelEntityType.GetSchemaQualifiedTableName();

            if (tableName == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("There's no coresponding table mapped to the input class");
            }

            return tableName;

        }
```

Where T is a generic type, if you have,for example, Employees table modeled based on Employee entity, you could use typeof(Employee)

Comment: Thanks but how would one add a row to a dynamic table?  I have the table's name, type, etc. but just not sure how to replace dbContext.Table1.Add(ob1); with something like dbContext.Find("Table1").Add(ob1);